# Print sum of squared digits of an integer (TASM)

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I'm trying to solve one simple task in assembly (TASM), namely:

> There is a natural number with a range in the word, determine the sum of digits in the second degree by this number.

I want to output to DOS the result of adding `6^2 + 1^2 + 3^2 + 1^2 + 3^2`.

The below code can only output a number in DOS, no more, given by our instructor.

```
;stack segments
stk segment stack 
    db  128 dup(?)
stk ends

;data segment 
data    segment para public 'data'
x   dw  61313
DThousands  dw  ?
Thousands   dw  ?
Hundreds    dw  ?
Decades     dw  ?
Units       dw  ?
result      dw  ?
data    ends    

;command segment 
code    segment para public 'code'      
    assume  cs:code, ds:data, ss:stk
begin:  
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov ax, x ; заносим число x в регистр ax
    mov result, ax ; заносим в зарезервированный участок памяти result значение из ax
    mov     ax, result ; меняем значение
    xor cx, cx  ;MOV CX, 0
    mov bx, 10 ; bx = 10
m_do_while:
    xor dx, dx ; обнуление dx
    div bx ; деление ax на bx
    push    dx ; заталкиваем dx в стек
    inc cx ; увеличиваем cx на 1
    cmp ax, 0 ; сравниваем регистр ax с нулем
    jne m_do_while ; выполняем условный переход
    mov ah, 2 ; помещаем в регистр ah 2
m_for:
    pop dx ; достаем из стека значение dx
    add dx, 30h ; прибавляем к dx 30h
    int 21h ; системное прерывание 
    loop    m_for ; цикл
back:
;end of program
    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
code    ends
    end begin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already getting the digits one at a time with that printing loop.  Addition is associative so it doesn't matter what order you get them in, you can add starting with the least-significant digit.

```
digit_sum:
    mov   ax, x       ; input in AX
    mov   bx, 10      ; base 10
    xor   cx, cx      ; sum
.sumloop:
    xor   dx, dx
    div   bx          ; quotient in AX,  remainder (the digit) in DX

  ;; With 386
    ;imul  dx, dx      ; requires 386
    ;add   cx, dx      ; sum += digit^2

  ;; Without 386
    xchg   ax, dx
    mul    al          ; result in AX.  DX untouched.  single-digit numbers fit in AL
    add    cx, ax      ; sum += digit^2
    mov    ax, dx

    test  ax, ax
    jne  .sumloop

;;; sum in CX
    ret
```

Then print `cx` efficiently, e.g. by converting into a buffer starting from the end and then making one print system call.  ([How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166064/how-do-i-print-an-integer-in-assembly-level-programming-without-printf-from-the/46301894#46301894)).  I wouldn't recommend that clunky push/pop 2-loop method you show in the question, but it's popular and does work.  Anyway, `mov ax, cx` would put the sum in AX.

You could even get some code-reuse by using a divide-by-10-and-push loop like you have, or like in [Assembly 8086 | Sum of an array, printing multi-digit numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40503119/assembly-8086-sum-of-an-array-printing-multi-digit-numbers/40505938#40505938).  The first time, use it to get digits which you pop and square -> sum.  The second time, use it to generate digits of the sum, which you pop and print.  (But writing a function that leaves a variable amount of stuff on the stack is tricky; you could pop the return address at the start of the function, then push/ret.  Or just make it a macro that you use twice, so it inlines both places.)

---

If you wanted to be 8086-compatible but tune for more recent Intel CPUs (where [`xchg` is 3 uops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766444/why-is-xchg-reg-reg-a-3-micro-op-instruction-on-modern-intel-architectures) and thus costs about the same as 3 mov instructions): Instead of `xchg ax,dx` you could use `mov si, ax` / `mov ax, dx`, then mul/add, then `mov ax, si`.  For actual ancient 8086, `xchg` is great: smaller is faster (except for really slow instructions like mul and div) and `xchg`-with-ax is only 1 byte.

Of course if you actually care about speed you'd use [a multiplicative inverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183935/why-does-gcc-use-multiplication-by-a-strange-number-in-implementing-integer-divi) to divide by 10.  And for actual 8086 where `mul` is quite slow (but not as slow as `div`), you might use a lookup-table of squares to save a mul in that part:

```
    ; given a digit in DX, add its square to CX, indexing a table of words
    mov si, dx
    shl si,1
    add cx, [table + si]
```

Or with just a table of bytes, trading 1 byte of extra code-size for a smaller table and 1 fewer byte of data loaded (break even on 8088, except for prefetch differences):

```
    mov si, dx
    add cl, [table + si]
    adc ch, 0              ; carry to the high half of CX
```

Comment: I feel awkward, but could you write a complete program to output the amount? Because my teacher gave me code to output numbers in DOs without explaining how it works and I'm confused about how to combine my code with your solutions

Comment: @Dsyder:  No thanks, I'm not interested in fully doing your homework for you.  Besides, you literally already have code that can output a number, given an input in AX.  If you want to understand the repeated division by 10 thing, read my answer on [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) and/or think through what happens.  [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45904075) also goes through the math in detail.

Comment: Thanks so much,I was able to combine your answer and my code and it works! Unfortunatelly, I can't upvote your answer :( But I thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your program takes the binary number from `x`, correctly displays it in decimal format: **61313** and then goes `back:` and ends. Code for computing squares of digits is missing.
Create a subprocedure which takes a binary digit in `dx` as its input, multiplies it with itself and accumulates the square into `sum`. The subprocedure shouldn't clobber any register:

```
SquareDX:     ; Let [sum] += DX*DX
     PUSH AX  
     PUSH DX
       MOV AX,DX
       MUL DX
       ADD [sum],AX   
     POP DX
     POP AX
     RET
```

Call the subprocedure after
`pop dx ; достаем из стека значение dx`
but before
`add dx, 30h ; прибавляем к dx 30h`

The last thing you need to do is to display the binary `sum` in decimal notation, exactly the same as you displayed the binary `x`.

Comment: Making a function for that seems overcomplicated.  Especially if you have a 386-compatible, `imul dx,dx` is easy, but even without that a couple `mov` instructions and a spare register (or `xchg ax,dx` around it) will let you `mul al` (result in AX without touching DX) / `add cx, ax`.    And why keep `[sum]` in memory?  x86 has enough registers for this.  You could even index a lookup table of squares with `mov si, dx` / `shl si,1` / `add cx, [table + bx]` which would be faster on a real 8086.

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed, making a separate function for each elementary task is uneffective, but it is good for comprehending and debugging. IMHO beginners in asm shouldn't be haunted with optimisation strategy in their first lessons.

Comment: Optimization is what makes it interesting to write / think about asm and post answers about it.  Thinking about optimization even helps understand why compilers generate code the way they do. Besides, fewer instructions are often easier to understand - some optimizations reduce the code to just the interesting part, stripping away noise.  (However, unlike the other points, the table-lookup idea doesn't fall into that category.  I just wanted to write down that idea somewhere.  I guess I should put it in my answer since I decided to write one.)

Answer (score -2):

At first you must to divide that number on 10000 if it > 9999, it will be your first char, next you transfert result by divided to any base register and same finding next char.

Comment: Repeated division by 10 extracts the digits 1 at a time just fine (as the remainder in dx), least-significant first.  Addition is associative so this is fine; the push and separate pop loop part is unnecessary.